# Webmatrix.WebData.WebSecurity with MySql is not working. Throwing sql syntax error in WebSecurity.UserExists() check

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership

I had a project done in MSSQL. I migrated MSSQL to MySql because i thought Webmatrix.WebData will support MySql also. WebSecurity initialiation was successful.

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
     {
          securityService.Initialize(
          "sqlserver",
          "UserProfile",
          "UserId"
          "UserName");
      };`
```

Above code executed successfully. But if fails to execute the following part,

```
 if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("user"))
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("user", "password");
        }
```

The check `WebSecurity.UserExists("user")` is failing. This is the error message-

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserTable] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = UPPER('user'))' at line 1

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSecurity shipped with ASP.Net (The one used in your code above) has some Microsoft T-SQL syntax embedded in the code. There are little differences between the MySQL syntax and MSSQL which probably accounts for the error.

From the error shown, I can see the `CreateUserAndAccount` method in WebSecurity somehow attempts to a execute the T-SQL statement `.... [UserId] FROM [UserTable] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = UPPER('user'))` however, while this would work in MSSQL, the square brackets `"["` and `"]"` would cause errors in MySQL.

A work around will be to use `MySql.Web.Security.MySqlWebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("user", "password")`, of cause,you can add a `using` statement or use it that way.

[see link](http://forums.asp.net/post/4821341.aspx)